# Return matching values, exclude the ones that aren't matching, remove duplicates MYSQL

Tags: mysql, match

I have a problem that I can't seem to solve. I have a table that tracks userID's and app ID's. The table looks like this:

```
Library:
ID        userID       appID
1           1          11122            
2           1          65324
3           1          43435
4           2          43435
5           2          50645
6           2          34343
7           4          11122
8           4          55343
```

The query should do the following:

- Return all appID values that selected users have in common. (If user 4 and user 1 are selected and both have the app 11122 it should show app 11122)
- Exclude the ones that aren't matching (Remove the ones they don't have in common. In this example it would be remove ids (55343, 65324 and 43435)
- Remove duplicate results (It should not list the same app twice. So appID 11122 should show only once)

Here's a PHP example of what I'm trying to do:

```
    $array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
    $array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
    $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Results would be "green" and "red"

Is this possible through MySQL?

Comment: I've tried a few different things. One of them "SELECT DISTINCT appID FROM library WHERE userID = 1 OR userID = 2", but this query shows ones that aren't matching for both users. There was also a UNION ALL query that I've found, but it didn't seem to be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you could try this:**

```
select a.appID from Library a
inner join
(select appID,count(ID) as ctr from Library where userID in(1,4) group by appID) b on b.appID = a.appID
where b.ctr > 1
group by a.appID;
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a077/19)

**update:**

i'm not sure if you want to view the common user ids into 1 column only

```
select a.appID,group_concat(a.userID) as user_ids from Library a
inner join
(select appID,count(ID) as ctr from Library where userID in(1,4) group by appID) b on b.appID = a.appID
where b.ctr > 1
group by a.appID;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0ed6/1)

Comment: Thanks! That's almost what I need. It works when it's two user ID's in the "WHERE userID IN" statement, but more than that it doesn't show common results. It looks like it takes the ids with the most in common first, without filtering out the rest. Not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I completely understand your question, but it sounds like you want to return userID 1 and 2 because they are associated with the same appID (actually twice).  If so, then this should work:

```
select L.userID, L.appID
from Library L
    join (
      select appID
      from Library
      group by appId
      having count(distinct userID) > 1
) L2 on L.appID = L2.appID
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86e0f/2)

And if you just need the unique userID, remove appID from the above query and add DISTINCT.